# Licensing of QGIS libraries

Tags: qgis, library

what type of license are subject to the following QGIS libraries?

libqgis_analysis.so

libqgis_core.so

libqgis_gui.so

I would like to use the following libraries released in QGIS package in a "close" (not open source) application. 
Are there any derived-license isusses ??

Answer (score 4):

QGIS is under the GPL license

http://www.qgis.org/

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.0.html

Comment: To elaborate more, if you use these libraries in a project then that project will need to be licensed as GPL and the source code will need to be provided to the users.  So if you are creating a closed source project then I would look for libraries that are non-gpl to use.

Comment: This is only the case if you distribute your app